# How does one get FIM exchange rates prior to 1999?

Tags: data-request, exchange-rates, history, data

I have long known of and used the data from: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html

But it only goes back to February 1999. FIM (Finnish Mark) stopped existing a month prior to that date. I'm trying to get FIM exchange rates prior to 1999 (when it existed), as far back as possible.

I don't have money to pay for this data. I have spend many hours searching (and asking) for this before asking here.

Comment: https://www.poundsterlinglive.com/bank-of-england-spot/historical-spot-exchange-rates/usd/USD-to-FIM

Comment: @AKdemy Thanks, but how can it have an exchange rate after 1999, in fact up until today?

Comment: downloadable: https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/productivity/pwt/
Penn world tables 10.1 for yearly data (it says EUR but obviously is FIM converted). 

If you have access to a University Library, you can look it up at a Bloomberg terminal (if the University has it).  Mmany universities and libraries like the New York Public Library have Windows PCs running Bloomberg Terminal software.

Comment: After 1999 is no FIM - you simply have EUR - if you want FIM (for say legacy bond pricing), you simply use the EUR exchange rate and compute the equivalent FIM (exchange rate is fixed). Bloomberg would do that for you as well (but it's simple to do manually).